# rewrite vk mp3 и воспроизведение браузером

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Музыка у меня rewrite-ица из Вк. И заголовки выставляет сам вк. Можно как-то
заменить эти заголовки, чтобы скачивалось, а не воспроизводилось браузером?
Сейчас content-type Vk выставляет **audio/mpeg** и браузер вместо скачивания
начинает воспроизводить музыку.

Как знаете, для скачивания файла нужны заголовки content-type
**application/octet-stream**.mp3. Вопрос в том, как
заменить мне эти заголовки?
Ссылки на файл берутся из вк и через ререйт меняются под домен. 
Пример:

`RewriteRule ^down/ ([0-9a-z]+)-([0-9]+)- ([0-9a-z]+)/(.*).mp3$ http://cs$1.vk.me/u $2/audios/$3.mp3 [NC,P]`

Answer (score 2):

"Что делать с результатом запроса" определяет HTTP-заголовок `Content-Disposition` ([RFC2616, секция 19.5.1](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html), производная [RFC1806](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1806.txt)).

`attachment` в этом заголовке означает *"не показывать прямо в документе, открывать только явно"*, браузеры это в наше время интерпретируют, как *"скачать и показать в списке загрузок"*.

*"Предложи это сохранить под именем `fname.ext`"* на языке HTTP будет так:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="fname.ext"
```

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно использовать атрибут [download](http://htmlbook.ru/html/a/download) в html ссылке

```
<a href="myfile.mp3" download>Скачать файл</a>
```